# split tuple with multiple bags into multiple tuples

Tags: apache-pig

I have my data as:

{(2000),(1800),(2700)}
{(2014),(1500),(1900)} etc.
I have created a java UDF:

```
DataBag bag = (DataBag)input.get(0);

    Tuple categoryCode = null; 
    Tuple auxiliary = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(3);

    int i = 0;
    for(Iterator<Tuple> code=bag.iterator(); code.hasNext();) {
        categoryCode=code.next();
        auxiliary.set(i, categoryCode.get(0).toString());
        i+=1;
    }

    return auxiliary.toDelimitedString(",");
```

I want my output to be like below in different columns:

2000    1800    2700
2014    1500    1900 etc
My UDF gives me the output as:

2000,1800,2700
2014,1500,1900 etc in a single column
Please help whether there is some other solution for this. Please help with your inputs.

Comment: Can you post the full UDF code please?

Comment: public class BagToAtom extends EvalFunc<String>
{ 
 public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        DataBag bag = (DataBag)input.get(0);

        Tuple categoryCode = null; 
        Tuple auxiliary = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(3);

        int i = 0;
        for(Iterator<Tuple> code=bag.iterator(); code.hasNext();) {
            categoryCode=code.next();
            auxiliary.set(i, categoryCode.get(0).toString());
            i+=1;
        }

        return auxiliary.toDelimitedString(",");
    }   

}

Answer (score 0):

You can return the tuple as is and do flatten in the pig script.